# Файл доступен по http, но не доступен по https

Tags: http, https

У меня есть файл

```
http://web4u.in.ua/source/sites/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA.gif_85892a815db69395e9a3b77ee76d79da.gif
```

Он открывается, а вот если открывать по такой ссылке

```
https://web4u.in.ua/source/sites/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA.gif_85892a815db69395e9a3b77ee76d79da.gif
```

не открывается. Почему так? Сайт нормально работает по https, при этом есть файлы, которые открываются по https, например этот

```
https://web4u.in.ua/source/sites/Dimteh.jpg_d5f14c971af6ca1d1918e89a17e0d541.jpg
```

Comment: Не знаю, как у Вас, а у меня тут обе ссылки (и http и https) совершенно одинаково выдают 404. (Третья ссылка открывается нормально)

Comment: Не стоит названия изображений держать в кириллице - это плохая практика. Проверьте наличие данных файлов на диске. Вполне возможно, что они там отсутствуют вовсе. И, без уточняющих вопросов тут не обойтись: - Какая ОСь? - Apache или nginx? Возможно полезная тема: https://searchengines.guru/showthread.php?p=11136135

Comment: Без конкретного конфига сайта ничего конкретного ответить не получится

Comment: спасибо, походу дело действительно в том, что картинки названы на кирилице